# materializecss font Icons is not Working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/78125vs0/109/)

Materialize icons (Location icon, please refer to the [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGvUL.png)) are not working in IE9. IE10+, Chrome & Firefox are working fine.
What have I done wrong?

```
<a class='dropdown-button waves-effect Default zone-dropdown' href='#!' data-activates='zone-dropdown'>Locations <i class="Tiny material-icons">room</i></a>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize#user-content-supported-browsers  This plugin doesn't support IE10< (IE9, IE8,...,IE4)

Comment: There is any solution with  JQuery or JavaScript?